# java Rectangle：why error "getPreferredSize()"

Tags: java, swt

Why error this code:

```
layout.setConstraint(andy, new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), andy.getPreferredSize()));
```

Error：

```
The constructor Rectangle(Point, Dimension) is undefined
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The constructor Rectangle(Point, Dimension) is undefined
The constructor Rectangle(Point, Dimension) is undefined
The constructor Rectangle(Point, Dimension) is undefined

at testdot.testdot.createDiagram(testdot.java:66)
at testdot.testdot.run(testdot.java:23)
at testdot.testdot.main(testdot.java:92)
```

I don't understand the error.
Please help debugging the error code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import org.eclipse.draw2d.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class testdot {

private void run() {
       Shell shell = new Shell(new Display());
       shell.setSize(365, 280);
       shell.setText("Genealogy");
       shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
       Canvas canvas = createDiagram(shell);
       canvas.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
       Display display = shell.getDisplay();
       shell.open();
       while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
          while (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
             display.sleep();
          }
       }
    }
private IFigure createPersonFigure(String name) {
       RectangleFigure rectangleFigure = new RectangleFigure();
       rectangleFigure.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.lightGray);
       rectangleFigure.setLayoutManager(new ToolbarLayout());
       rectangleFigure.setPreferredSize(100, 100);
       rectangleFigure.add(new Label(name));
       return rectangleFigure;
    }




private Canvas createDiagram(Composite parent) {
       // Create a root figure and simple layout to contain
       // all other figures
       Figure root = new Figure();
       root.setFont(parent.getFont());
       XYLayout layout = new XYLayout();
       root.setLayoutManager(layout);
       // Add the father "Andy"
       IFigure andy = createPersonFigure("Andy");
       root.add(andy);
       layout.setConstraint(andy,
       new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), andy.getPreferredSize()));
       // Add the mother "Betty"
       IFigure betty = createPersonFigure("Betty");
       root.add(betty);
       layout.setConstraint(betty,
       new Rectangle(new Point(230, 10), betty.getPreferredSize()));
       // Add the son "Carl"
       IFigure carl = createPersonFigure("Carl");
       root.add(carl);
       layout.setConstraint(carl,
       new Rectangle(new Point(120, 120), carl.getPreferredSize()));



       // Create a canvas to display the root figure
       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED);
       canvas.setBackground(ColorConstants.white);
       LightweightSystem lws = new LightweightSystem(canvas);
       lws.setContents(root);
       return canvas;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
          new testdot().run();
       }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this (or something like it) 3 times in your code:

```
     new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), andy.getPreferredSize()));
```

It is not compilable Java.  As the compilation error message says:

```
     constructor Rectangle(Point, Dimension) is undefined
```

Why is it saying that?  After all, there is a `Rectangle(Point, Dimension)` constructor in `java.awt.Rectangle` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#Rectangle(java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Dimension))).

Well lets look at the actual types.

- The first argument is clearly a `java.awt.Point`.  OK.
- The second argument is a result of a method call on an `IFigure` instance.  Hmmm.

If you look at the documentation for `IFigure` you will see that the `getPreferredSize` methods return a `org.eclipse.draw2d.geometry.Dimension` object, not an `java.awt.Dimension`.

Basically, you are mixing up SWT and AWT types.

```
import java.awt.*;
```

That is wrong.  Since you are (apparently) programming for the Eclipse / SWT platform, you should be importing and using SWT classes exclusively.  Mixing SWT with AWT (or Swing or JavaFX or Android) apis is going to lead to problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you do gave me a big favor !!